# Relationship between gradient and position vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

When we take a derivative of the function `f(x)` with respect to `x` we find out how much an infinitely small change in `x` will change `f(x)`.

When we take the gradient of a multivariable function say `f(x,y,z)` we define it as

$$ \nabla.f(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x} \hat{i} + \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial y} \hat{j} + \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial z} \hat{k}
$$

and if the position vector is given by $ \vec{r}(x,y,z) = x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k} $

Then is it safe to correlate that the gradient is the directional derivative of the function with respect to the position vector $\vec{r}$

If I am wrong can you explain in detail why ?

Answer (score 2):

No, because the directional derivative of a function does not change it's "type", e.g. the directional derivative of a scalar-valued function is a scalar-valued function, not a vector-valued function.

But choose any vector $\vec v$ and calculate $v\cdot\nabla f$. You will find that this is the directional derivative (and perhaps you should review the definition of directional derivative). So the quantity you want is $\vec r\cdot\nabla f$; but note that $\vec r$ **does not** get differentiated in any way.

Answer (score 2):

When $f$ is a function of a single variable, there is only one direction (up to sign) in which one can differentiate; therefore one typically speaks of differentiating $f$ with respect to $x$.  But in several variables, the position vector $\vec r$ (i.e., the point at which one studies the change in the function) and the direction $v$ (in which the function is differentiated) are unrelated vectors and should not be confused.  What is true is that the directional derivative in the direction $v$ is given in terms of the gradient $\nabla f$ at the point $\vec r$ by the formula $v \cdot \nabla f$.

Note that the gradient at the point cannot be "the directional derivative in the direction of the position vector", since the former (gradient) is a vector whereas the latter (directional derivative in the direction of the position vector) is a scalar.

Comment: When we take the dot product of a vector say `a` with `b` we are taking the component(projection) of a vector `a` in the direction of `b` (scaled by the magnitude of `b` of course, but let's assume `b` is a unit vector). So, since we only care about the direction of `b` we do not need a direction for the dot product.  (I hope this is the correct way to understand it.)

When you apply this logic to the gradient and the directional derivative in the direction of the position vector wouldn't it work?
I wanted to know this with respect to your answer _"Note that the gradient at the point ..."_